# Check conncetion to AFP server through bash

Tags: network, command-line, bash, osx-server, afp

Is there any way to programmatically check if a connection is established to an afp server? I have tried pinging the server but that always results in a timeout.

So far the only workaround that I've gotten to work is:

```
#!/bin/bash
open "afp://website.com/afpDir/"
until [[ -d /Volumes/afpDir/ ]]; do
    echo 'waiting for connections'
    sleep 1
done
```

However, this only works if I specifically check for the `afpDir` directory while it is open in Finder. Is there a reliable way to to check if there is a connection to that afp server or perhaps even finding a reliable ip for the server?

Comment: What does the `mount` command return on your system - both when the AFP server is connected and disconnected?

Comment: @Scot mount gives me `//username@website.com/homedir on /Volumes/homedir (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, quarantine, mounted by localuser)` and it's gone when I unmount.

Comment: So, using `mount` and parsing the results is another possibility.

Comment: @Scot absolutely, it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a connection to an AFP server - with the fixed listening port 548 - is established use:

```
netstat -naf inet | grep [.]548[\ ].*ESTAB*
```

or with quotes:

```
netstat -naf inet | grep '[.]548[\ ].*ESTAB*'
```

with `-naf inet`: no name resolution, all sockets and restrict to IPv4

and `[.]548[\ ].*ESTAB*` (grep for an) `<IP-address>.548  ESTABLISHED`. The `[.]` is required to exclude ports like 2548 or 10548. `[\ ]` excludes ports like 5480 or 5481. The `.*` concatenates everything (tab/spaces) between 548 and ESTAB*.

An example result looks like this:

```
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.24.54340       192.168.1.2.548         ESTABLISHED
```

192.168.1.24 is the client's IP address and 192.168.1.2 the server's IP address then.

Comment: hmm I'm getting a no matches found  for `netstat -naf inet | grep [.]548[\ ].*ESTAB*` even when the server is confirmed to be mounted.

Comment: I did howerver get a *.548 match. Do you mind briefly explaining the use of the star and brackets? I was under the assumption that brackets was just a regex OR match for single chars.

Comment: @MicksKetches The `[.]` is required to exclude ports like 2548 or 10548. `[\ ]` excludes ports like 5480 or 5481. The `.*` concatenates everything (tab/spaces) between 548 and ESTAB*.

Comment: Update: I did get a desired outcome if I wrapped the statement in quotes like so: `netstat -naf inet | grep '[.]548[\ ].*ESTAB*'` I hope that was what you meant.